# Upload large file into server in android

Tags: android, performance

i have done the application for uploading the images from mobile to server through api call one by one manner.I have create the service and multipart entitiy to upload the images.It seems uploading images one by one using multipart is performance wise not good.Any other thrid party library to achieve the image uploading in asynchronous manner?

Comment: hy, y u not try first of convert image Bitmap. and after uploading images from mobile to server

Comment: say for example i have 500 images in my mobile..i have to upload it into server through api call.How to achieve this  performance wise better ..any idea?